# How can I calculate sql tables in delphi ?

Tags: sql, delphi

Hi I have sql table I want to calculate all the fields to total sum field. 
[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  You obviously can't include the `names` field in the total, so **exactly** which fields *do* you want to include?  What Sql Server are you using?

Comment: names field not  calc field. I want to include all fields except names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the SELECT statement you use to get the data, something like

```
SELECT *, big1 + small1 as "TotalSum" from adlar
```

Obviously, you can add more numeric fields to the fields to sum.

Answer (score 1):

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin

ADOQuery1.Close;

ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='select  boyuk1 + kicik1 + qara1 + boyuk2 + kicik2 + boyuk3 * 0,35 as totalsum from adlar2v';       //(table name:adlar2v)

ADOQuery1.Open;

end;