# How can I calculate all field and post (SQL/or onCalcFields)

Tags: sql, delphi

I want to calculate all fields and add a total field. How can I do this? I did this with sql command, but I don't know how to update `dbgrid` every time.
My code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOQuery1.Close;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select names,big1,small1,black1,big2,small2,big3,'+   
      '((big1+small1+black1+big2+small2+big3)*0.35) as total from adlar7v';
  ADOQuery1.Open; 
end;
```

when I run this code the first time it works, but the second time the changes don't appear in the grid.

Second method:

I did this with the `TAdoQuery.OnCalcField` event but there is a problem.
I know how to calculate a field but I don't know how to  multiply all field after addition

my code:

```
ADOQuery1.FieldValues['total'] := 
     ADOQuery1.FieldValues['big1'] + ADOQuery1.FieldValues['small1'] + 
     ADOQuery1.FieldValues['black1'] + ADOQuery1.FieldValues['big2'] + 
     ADOQuery1.FieldValues['small2'] + ADOQuery1.FieldValues['big3'];
```

---

ADOQuery1.FieldValues['cemi']:=((ADOQuery1.FieldValues['boyuk1'] + ADOQuery1.FieldValues['boyuk2'] + ADOQuery1.FieldValues['boyuk3'])*0.35)+((ADOQuery1.FieldValues['kicik1'] + ADOQuery1.FieldValues['kicik2'])*0.25)+(ADOQuery1.FieldValues['qara1']*0.30);

Hi I want to post calc field(cemi) to table (sql). when I calc all field the last field doesn't post on sql table. because last field (cemi) type fkcalc how can I post fkcalc type field Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291757

Comment: What do you mean by "second time" in your first method?  Do you mean that if you change the value in one of the number columns in the grid, the value in the "total" column of that row does not change?

Comment: do you want to total all fields in single row (horizontally) or a single column=field in all the rows (vertically) ? why do you even need multiplication ?

Comment: Yes martynA. exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I run this code first time working second time changes doesn't appear db grid

Use the Object Inspector to set up an AfterPost handler on your AdoQuery1:

```
procedure TForm1.ADOQuery1AfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  AdoQuery1.Refresh;
end;
```

Then, after you save a change to one of the numeric columns in the grid, the AdoQuery1.Refresh will cause the data to be retrieved again from the server, and that will cause the server to recalculate the "Total" column.  The fact that it isn't doing that at the moment is why the Total column isn't updating.

Btw, if I've understood what you are asking about that correctly, then your second point

> I know how to calculate field but don't know how to multiplication(*) all field after (+)

Use the following code for this

```
ADOQuery1.FieldValues['total'] := (
 ADOQuery1.FieldValues['big1'] + ADOQuery1.FieldValues['small1'] + 
 ADOQuery1.FieldValues['black1'] + ADOQuery1.FieldValues['big2'] + 
 ADOQuery1.FieldValues['small2'] + ADOQuery1.FieldValues['big3'] )
 * 0.35;
```

Comment: Thanks for your Useful comment. You helped me a lot. I appreciate this.

Comment: I mean I did this ADOQuery1.SQL.text:='select adlar,boyuk1,kicik1,qara1,boyuk2,kicik2,boyuk3,((boyuk1+kicik1+qara1+boyuk2+kicik2+boyuk3)*0.35) as  cemi from adlar7v';      how can I did this with oncalc event like this example : ADOQuery1.FieldValues['total']:=((ADOQuery1.FieldValues['boyuk1'] + ADOQuery1.FieldValues['kicik1'] + ADOQuery1.FieldValues['qara1'] + ADOQuery1.FieldValues['boyuk2'] + ADOQuery1.FieldValues['kicik2'] + ADOQuery1.FieldValues['boyuk3'])*0.35);   This approach can work? thanks in advance

Comment: You are the best programmer I have ever seen Thanks !